# Filter features in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there any way to apply a filter to a Vector source feature collection without modifying the collection? Just choosing what features are rendered or not. I guess this could be achieved by returning null for the filtered features style, but I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: That depends of what you mean by "rendered".  If you define a style function that renders some features and some others not, then you'd need to manage them manually.  If you only want those that are in the extent of the view of your map, then you could loop in your features and collect those that are within it.  Does that help ?

Comment: This question may be answered in here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170149/openlayers-3-toggle-feature-visibility (tells how style alpha or opacity can be used for an show&hide effect on features)

Comment: I mean filter as in the style function doesn't even get called for the filtered out features, to save out some processor cycles (i'm cycling through 10000+ features). I guess I could swap out the features collection entirely with the filtered one or do as sugested and simply return null as the style for the filtered out features.